# DeploymentException while deploying the remote EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss5.x

I am getting this exception while running a dynamic web project

```
Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA_1/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/BookMartEAR.ear/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying BookMartEJB.jar: Container jboss.j2ee:ear=BookMartEAR.ear,jar=BookMartEJB.jar,name=BookMartBean,service=EJB3 failed to resolve persistence unit BookMartEjb
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a persistence unit named 'BookMartEjb' in AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@26167457{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA_1/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/BookMartEAR.ear/BookMartEJB.jar/}
```

The EJB, EAR and Web project names are as mentioned.

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="BookMartEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.misys.book.Book</class>
        <class>com.misys.book.Sale</class>
        <class>com.misys.book.Saleitem</class>
        <class>com.misys.book.Customer</class>
        <class>com.misys.book.User</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

is there any problem with this xml file?
I am using JBoss AS server, and MySql database.

Kindly suggest where I could have gone wrong. Also, tell if any other information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the location of `persistence.xml` in your EAR? It should be inside the META-INF folder of your EJB module. If it's not there (e.g. it's in the EAR root or in the web module), then it indeed can not be found.

Also, if the persistence unit eventually is going to be found you might run into the next problem. Your data source is set to just `MySqlDS`, but most likely this should be `java:/MySqlDS` as that's the location JBoss AS will bind data sources to.

Further unrelated to your question, but you probably don't have to list your classes explicitly. Unless you don't want run-time scanning to occur but then you also have to include the `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>` element. (oh, and one last thing JTA is already the default so you could also leave out transaction-type="JTA")

Comment: thanx 4 replying...Ya persistance.xml is in EJB module..i changed it to java:/MySqlDS.. The persistance error is gone...However, am not yet being able to run the project. It throws the same exception. Ne other suggestions?

Comment: I just noticed something else. The error complains about BookMartEjb not being found, but the name of your PU is BookMartEJB. Those names need to be exactly the same. (you might want to rename your pu name to BookMarkPU: *persistence-unit name="BookMartPU"* so you can clearly scan at what locations are using the old name)